# Is it possible to use org-mode links to navigate inside source code

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Given:

1. elisp files with source code
2. org file with documentation

Scheme of a typical source file:

```
;header, describing <code snippet 1>
<code snippet 1>

;header, describing <code snippet 2>
<code snippet 2>
...
;header, describing <code snippet n>
<code snippet n>
```

Scheme of an org file:

```
* <file_name.el>
1. [[./<file_name.el>::1][header, describing <code snippet 1>]]
2. [[./<file_name.el>::<line of header 2>][header, describing <code snippet 2>]]
...
n. [[./<file_name.el>::<line of header n>][header, describing <code snippet n>]]
```

org file is currently manually created by me. When I click upon the link, I am redirected to the appropriate line of the file. But when the source file is modified, I am redirected to a wrong line.

Is it possible to change the function, that is called, when I click upon the link, so it searched for the regexp: `"^;header, describing <code snippet n>"` instead of redirecting me to the fixed line number?

Maybe, you could suggest me a better way of creating a mapping between the org file and appropriate places of another text file?

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you might want to look at [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming), in which code and documentation are interspersed. org-mode (more specifically [babel](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html)) provides extensive support for such techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define anchors in your source file (i.e. words which will not be present anywhere else in your file), and link to them in the org-file:

```lisp
; <<foo>>
(defun foo ())

; <<bar>>
(defun bar ())
```

```
- [[file:source.el::<<foo>>][foo]]
- [[file:source.el::<<bar>>][bar]]
```

This type of "text search" link is only [officially documented](http://orgmode.org/org.html#External-links) for org-files, but I suspect it works for every text-based file.